# Could not load properties error in spring PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer

Tags: spring

I have the following code, using a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner sc=null;
    CustomerDTO dto=null;
    //create IOC Container
    ApplicationContext ctx=new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/java/com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml");
    //get PropertyPlaaceHolderConfigurer OBJ
    BeanFactoryPostProcessor bfpp=ctx.getBean("ppc",PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
    bfpp.postProcessBeanFactory((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)ctx);

    sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Customer NO: ");
    int cno=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Customer Name: ");
    String cname=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Principal Amount:: ");
    float pamt=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter Rate of Interest: ");
    float rate=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter Time/Period: ");
    float time=sc.nextFloat();

    //set values to dto
    dto=new CustomerDTO();
    dto.setCno(cno);
    dto.setCname(cname);
    dto.setPamt(pamt);
    dto.setRate(rate);
    dto.setTime(time);

    //getBean
    LoanService service=ctx.getBean("service",LoanService.class);
    System.out.println(service.calcIntrAmt(dto));       
}
```

The code above gives me the following error:

```
Aug 04, 2018 8:16:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@621be5d1: startup date [Sat Aug 04 20:16:08 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 04, 2018 8:16:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [D:\NTSP710\IOC-Beans28ApplicationContextWithPropertyFileConfigurator\src\main\java\com\nt\cfgs\applicationContext.xml]
Aug 04, 2018 8:16:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\java\com\nt\commons\DBDetails.properties
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\java\com\nt\commons\DBDetails.properties
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.nt.test.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\java\com\nt\commons\DBDetails.properties
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:129)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80)
    ... 7 more
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: where is your applicationContext.xml actually ....   ? can you add project structure

Answer (score 0):

You should put your application context in src/main/resources/com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml, then try reading it with just "com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml" ... Your class does not get executed from the top of your project, but rather from within the target folder - so it cannot see the path you indicate relative to "target".

Or better yet, use a classpath context reader and the path "classpath:com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml" ...

Answer (score 0):

The exception is straightforward. It says

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\java\com\nt\commons\DBDetails.properties
```

This means that it's not able to find the `DBDetails.properties` file in the path given. You need to provide the correct path of the same either in `applicationContext.xml` or `@PropertySource`, wherever you have defined it.

Comment: @SnigdhaMishra did this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for a .xml file, It wasted lot of my time, eventually I followed these steps to fix it:

1. Delete your project (or multiple related projects) and its sub-project if any from workspace (don't delete it from your computer disk).
2. Import the project again, Mine was from git so I did "Import from GIT"
3. Once import is complete, clean install from pom.xml
4. Then try running the main class.

There could be a better solution but this fixed my issue,
Might help others too.